# Docker intercontainer communication

Tags: hadoop, docker, dockerfile, flume

I would like to run `Hadoop` and `Flume` dockerized. I have a standard `Hadoop` image with all the default values. I cannot see how can these services communicate each other placed in separated containers.

`Flume`'s `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y --no-install-recommends wget

RUN mkdir /opt/java
RUN wget --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" -qO- \
  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jre-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz \
  | tar zxvf - -C /opt/java --strip 1

RUN mkdir /opt/flume
RUN wget -qO- http://archive.apache.org/dist/flume/1.6.0/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin.tar.gz \
  | tar zxvf - -C /opt/flume --strip 1

ADD flume.conf /var/tmp/flume.conf
ADD start-flume.sh /opt/flume/bin/start-flume

ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/java
ENV PATH /opt/flume/bin:/opt/java/bin:$PATH

CMD [ "start-flume" ]

EXPOSE 10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link your containers. There are some variants how you can implement this.

1) Publish ports:

`docker run -p 50070:50070 hadoop`

option `p` binds port 50070 of your docker container with port 50070 of host machine

2) Link containers (using docker-compose)

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
 hadoop:
  image: hadoop:2.6
 flume:
 image: flume:last
 links:
 - hadoop
```

link option here binds your flume container with hadoop

more info about this https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Comment: Why 50070 is the port number?

Comment: It is just random port, you can use ports what you need instead this

Comment: Should be a Hadoop port? Which?